# Angular 2 How do I make a div appear that is based in a parent container

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to have my loading modal pop-up at the parent component (ie "app.component.ts"). Reason being is that I need to call to it several times throughout the app and I don't wish to have to paste it to every page.

I then have pages which are several routes down which need to be able to turn that loading modal screen on and off. Is the best way to do this via a service, or using input?

Answer (score 1):

You can always emit event to parent (app.component) to show modal-popup.

app.component.html

```
<div>
     <child-component (onShow)="showPopup($event)"></child-component>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
public showPopup(show : boolean){
   if(show){
   /* code to show popup goes there */
   }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Output() onShow= new EventEmitter()<boolean>; 

    public someFunc(){
    /*once you are ready to show popup */
    this.onShow.emit(true);
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Just trying that but my text editor says that "cannot find name Output and cannot find name EventEmitter".

Comment: You need to import them.  `import {Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward  
If my answer has solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.